# C# Windows 7 Request Admin Privileges(Special Situation)

Tags: c#, visual-studio-2013, administrator

I created an C# application and here is my manifest file which is created on Visual Studio 2013

```
 <?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
<assembly manifestVersion="1.0" xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v1">
 <assemblyIdentity version="1.0.0.0" name="MyApplication.app"/>
 <trustInfo xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v2">
<security>
    <requestedPrivileges xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:asm.v3">



    <requestedExecutionLevel  level="requireAdministrator" uiAccess="false" />



  </requestedPrivileges>
  </security>
  </trustInfo>

  <compatibility xmlns="urn:schemas-microsoft-com:compatibility.v1">
  <application>
    <!-- Windows Vista -->
   <supportedOS Id="{e2011457-1546-43c5-a5fe-008deee3d3f0}" />

  <!-- Windows 7 -->
  <supportedOS Id="{35138b9a-5d96-4fbd-8e2d-a2440225f93a}" />

  <!-- Windows 8 -->
  <supportedOS Id="{4a2f28e3-53b9-4441-ba9c-d69d4a4a6e38}" />

  <!-- Windows 8.1 -->
  <supportedOS Id="{1f676c76-80e1-4239-95bb-83d0f6d0da78}" />

  <!-- Windows 10 -->
  <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" />-

</application>
</compatibility>
<dependency>
  <dependentAssembly>
    <assemblyIdentity
        type="win32"
        name="Microsoft.Windows.Common-Controls"
      version="6.0.0.0"
      processorArchitecture="*"
      publicKeyToken="6595b64144ccf1df"
      language="*"
    />
  </dependentAssembly>
   </dependency>
</assembly>
```

Since I have an manifest file, my program doesnt run on SOME windows 7 OS. It gives access denied error. Some how It runs on SOME windows 7 OS PC's.(Actually It runs on all win10 PC's) I read possible duplicate articles on stackoverflow and I tried all possible things to do. Do you suggest something else? Please help me. Thank you.

Comment: "It gives access denied error" do you mean when you launch your program you can't because you get access denied or you are doing some operation in your code that you get access denied even though you have requireAdministrator set in the manifest?

Comment: Side note, is there an invalid char in <application> <!-- Windows 10 -->
  <supportedOS Id="{8e0f7a12-bfb3-4fe8-b9a5-48fd50a15a9a}" /> `-`